# Is it possible that socket() returns the same integer value as that of a previously closed socket?

Tags: sockets

In other words, how does the system choose an integer as its descriptor when creating a new socket?

If that is possible, then we cannot `recv` or `send` on a socket after it's been closed, because the `recv`/`send` might be actually operating on a socket that was created (so return no error) as soon as the old socket had been closed. Am I right?

In a program where two threads operate on the same socket, it is likely that after one thread has closed the socket, the other still attempts to `recv/send` on it.

Comment: Certainly. Very likely, in fact.

Comment: The numbers are re-used.  On UNIX/Linux systems, the number returned by `socket` is a file descriptor from the same range as those returned by `open`, which is why `close` is used to close both files and sockets.

Comment: you need to separately maintain some state to indicate whether the socket fd is believed to represent an open socket or not

Comment: "we cannot recv or send on a socket after it's been closed, ". Regardless of the exact numerical details, that statement is always true. "In an program where two threads operate on the same socket, it is likely that after one thread has closed the socket, the other still attempts to recv/send on it.". No, it isn't. The first thread *must not* close a socket that's still in use.

Answer (score 2):

[POSIX specifies how the system allocates file descriptors](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_14):

> #### 2.14. File Descriptor Allocation
>
> All functions that open one or more file descriptors shall, unless specified otherwise, atomically allocate the lowest numbered available (that is, not already open in the calling process) file descriptor at the time of each allocation. Where a single function allocates two file descriptors (for example, `pipe()` or `socketpair()`), the allocations may be independent and therefore applications should not expect them to have adjacent values or depend on which has the higher value.

Therefore it is guaranteed that a process that allocates a file descriptor, closes it, and then allocates another file descriptor will reuse a file descriptor.

The problem you're describing, of one thread closing a file descriptor that another thread is also using, is a common multithreaded programming error. You need to handle it by managing the file descriptor (a kernel-level object) with some application-level object, where you can track whether the object (socket, file, whatever) referred to be the file descriptor is still accessible by that file descriptor.